# Parámetros por default en la URL en symfony 4.3.5

Tags: php, url, symfony

ando iniciándome en symfony y tengo esta situación.

Leo en la documentación que es posible en una ruta de anotación forzar a que el URL incluya el parámetro por default del método coincidente, según leí basta con poner el carácter ! antes del nombre del parámetro: /blog/{!page}

Tengo el siguiente código donde busco probar esta característica (tomado de la documentación de Symfony)

```
// src/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; 

class BlogController  
{
        /**
        * @Route("/blog/{page}", name="blog_list")
        */
        public function list(int $page = 1)
        {
            return new Response( 
               '<html></body>Lucky number: '.$page.'</body></html>'
            );
        }

}
```

Así como está funciona sin problemas, si escribo en mi navegador:

```
http://localhost/index.php/blog
```

Imprime el valor, pero cuando intento forzar a que el URL muestre el valor por defecto haciendo justamente lo que menciona la documentación, poniéndole ! antes del nombre del parámetro en la ruta {!page} quedando a ruta de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
  * @Route("/blog/{!page}", name="blog_list")
*/
```

Marca el siguiente error:

```
No route found for "GET /blog"
```

NO se si estoy leyendo mal la documentación pero no ubico que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento que indicas es correcto.

El modificador `!` espera un valor para el parámetro `page`. Este se añade automáticamente a las URL generadas con el `Router`.

```php
/**
* @Route("/blog/{!page}", name="blog_list")
*/
public function list(int $page = 1)
```

El `path` generado para la primera página sería: `/blog/1`. Si necesitas que sea `/blog/`, puedes optar por crear otro `action`:

```php
/**
* @Route("/blog/", name="blog_main_list")
*/
public function mainList()
```

O bien puedes optar por la primera solución que propones:

```php
/**
* @Route("/blog/{page}", name="blog_list")
*/
public function list(int $page = 1)
```